# Can I make a keyed service for AutoFac based on the type of the Open Generic

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, decorator, autofac, command-pattern

I would like to make a keyedService based on the T for my Open Generic ICommandHandler. I would like to register a ConsultatCommandHanlder keyed service when the ICommandHandler has a T that inherits from ConsultantCommand

Any idea how to do it? Or if it is even possible? I am new to AutoFac and am struggling.

I am presently registering CommandHandler like this:

```
        //Register All Command Handlers
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
          .As(
              t =>
              t.GetInterfaces()
               .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof (ICommandHandler<>)))
               .Select(a => new KeyedService("commandHandler", a))).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

If it is possible I'd guess I have to identify the CommandHandlers when I get the Closed Type and in some way identify the ones where the Command implements ConsultantCommand.

I tried:

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
               .As(
                 t =>
                   t.GetInterfaces()
                    .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)) &&
                        a.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(ConsultantCommand)))
                    .Select(a => new KeyedService("ConsultantCommandHandler", a))).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

But not joy doesn't seem to work. It compiles but now no CommandHandlers are registered even those that do inherit from ConsultantCommand. I think my syntax is all wrong

Comment: Can you supply us with a bit more background info on why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to decorate certain classes of commands after successful completion or perhaps before they run so I can carry our certain actions within the system. E.g email or clear cache

Comment: What you are trying to do seems more reasonable for event handlers. There should typically be a one to one correspondence between a command and a handler. Instead of splitting the logic in multiple command handlers,  create one handler with a dependency on multiple services that contain that logic.

Comment: Yeah. I am using Udi Dahans domain event pattern.  So if a person is updated it raises an event called PersonUpdated and event handlers can listen and clear cache send email etc. As a matter of interest could Simple Injector conditionally add a decorator? BTW thanks for your well written Command articles great help to explain the logic of the command/handler pattern and reason for splitting to our team.

Comment: You're welcome. Simple Injector has IMO the best support for conditional decorators of all containers. You can use the `RegisterDecorator` overload for that that takes a predicate. The predicate will just be evaluated once per closed type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to make sure your `ICommandHandler<T>` is declared to support covariance:

```
public interface ICommandHandler<out T> { }
```

That `out` is important or you won't be able to resolve all the `ConsultantCommand` handlers at once. You'll also get an Autofac exception.

Next, use the `Named` extension method to register your named service rather than doing it yourself. The syntax will look something like this:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .Where(t =>
                t.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)) &&
                t.GetInterfaces()[0]
                 .GetGenericArguments()[0]
                 .IsAssignableTo<ConsultantCommand>())
       .Named("name", typeof(ICommandHandler<ConsultantCommand>))
       .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

That registers all of the services that are `ICommandHandler<T>` where `T` derives from `ConsultantCommand` as an `ICommandHandler<ConsultantCommand>`. You have to use the base type or, again, you won't be able to resolve all the handlers at once. There isn't any method to "resolve all the services that derive from this base type." There's also no way to resolve a list of open generics.

When you resolve the list of handlers, you'll need to resolve a named `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var x =
    scope.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ConsultantCommand>>>("name");
}
```

Of course, you're using `InstancePerHttpRequest` so it'd be more like:

```
var x =
  AutofacDependencyResolver
    .Current
    .RequestLifetimeScope
    .ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<ConsultantCommand>>>("name");
```

As mentioned above, you have to register as a closed generic because this won't work:

```
// WON'T WORK:
scope.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<>>>("name");
```

You can modify the registration and such as needed. The rest of the registration extensions should work as usual - if you want to register things as implemented interfaces or whatever else, it should work with `RegisterAssemblyTypes` just like you were doing it with a single service.

Comment: That looks awesome, thanks for taking the time to write it up. I just needed to be able to decorate those commands so I should be able to do that with this. If I want to use constructor injection in an MVC Controller for a command handler like e.g. ICommandHandler<ChangeConsultantAddress> I'd still be able to do that?

Comment: [Without running this through a compiler] you should be able to if you not only use "Named" but also throw an "As()" on the registration. Basically you need to register each command handler as two things - first, the named service (for your collection) and second, the more specific ICommandHandler<T> that you just mentioned. One of the "As" syntax options should cover you.

Comment: My interface for ICommandHandler<TCommand> has a void method Handle(TCommand command) so I can't declare out to support covariance. Think I'm just trying to force something that maybe shouldn't be done.

Comment: Sorry to hear it won't work out like you planned. If this or one of the other answers got you the info you needed to determine that, you might consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: Yeah if you don't know a way to make AutoFac do it then it isn't possible. I just registered a Decorator around all CommandHandlers and then tested the type in there. Not as clean as I wanted it but best that looks possible

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
       .AsSelf()
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Sorry new to Autofac Doesn't that just register all the ICommandHandlers? How can I tell which ones are ICommandHandler<T> where T inherits from ConsultantCommand?