# Issue registering generic types with Autofac in ASP.NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac

I'm a relatively new user of both Autofac and ASP.NET Core.  I've recently ported a small project from a 'classic' ASP.NET WebAPI project to ASP.NET Core.  I am having trouble with Autofac, specifically in registration of generic types.

This project uses a Command pattern, each command handler is a closed generic like

```
public class UpdateCustomerCommandHandler: ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>
```

These command handlers are injected into the controllers like:

```
readonly private ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand> _updateCustomerCommand;
public ValuesController(ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand> updateCustomerCommand)
{
    _updateCustomerCommand = updateCustomerCommand;
}
```

Autofac is configured (partially) as:

```
 var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
 var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
 //This doesn't seem to be working as expected.
 builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
     .As(t => t.GetInterfaces()
         .Where(a => a.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>)))
         .Select(a => new KeyedService("commandHandler", a)));
```

The above does not seem to be registering the generic as expected.  If I use the below method for registration, it works well.

```
 builder.RegisterType<UpdateCustomerCommandHandler>().As<ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>>();
```

When I say "It doesn't work", what I mean is that when attempting to instantiate the controller, I get "InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'BusinessLogic.ICommandHandler`1[BusinessLogic.UpdateCustomerCommand]' while attempting to activate 'AutoFac_Test.Controllers.ValuesController'."

This worked well in the Full WebAPI version of this project, but not after recreating it in ASP.NET Core.  To be clear, this was working perfectly well before porting to ASP.NET Core.

Here is a link to the code that I've used to recreate this issue:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/185950/AutoFac_Test.zip

**** EDIT AFTER SOLUTION DISCOVERED ****

There was nothing in fact wrong with my Autofac configuration and certainly not Autofac itself.  What had happened was that I had renamed the output of my dependent assemblies in an effort to make the assembly scanning stuff (replacing of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` more elegant, however I never modified the dependencies of the API project to reference the new assemblies.  So Autofac was scanning the correctly loaded assemblies which happened to be the older versions, which did not contain the interfaces and implementations I expected...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make a keyed service for AutoFac based on the type of the Open Generic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636492/can-i-make-a-keyed-service-for-autofac-based-on-the-type-of-the-open-generic)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this question is not a duplicate of that.  In that case, the requester was looking to register a generic deriving from a specific base and implementing a specific closed generic interface.  In my case, I am just looking to register implementations of a particular closed generic interface.  Moreover, the above syntax has been proved to work quite well in classic ASP.NET, but not in ASP.NET Core.  I'm wondering if something has changed in reflection that might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofac has built-in support to register closed types of open-generic.

```cs
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

This will scan your assembly, find types that close the open generic `ICommandHandler<>` interface, and register each of them against the closed generic interface they implement - in your case, `ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>`.

What doesn't work in your example is that you associate a key to your services. Autofac doesn't look for the keyed version of your `ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>` when trying to instantiate the `ValuesController`, which is why you get the exception.

*Edit after QuietSeditionist's comment:*

I'll try to elaborate a bit on the *keyed* vs. *default* services. The way you registered your handlers is by associating the `commandHandler` key to them.

This means that once the container is built, here's the only way you can resolve such a handler:

```cs
// container will look for a registration for ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand> associated with the "commandHandler" key
container.ResolveKeyed<ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>>("commandHandler");
```

When instantiating `ValuesController`, Autofac doesn't look for a *keyed* registration of `ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>`, because it wasn't asked to.

The equivalent code it's executing is - and you can try to run that code yourself to get the exception:

```cs
// BOOM!
container.Resolve<ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>>();
```

The reason your second registration works is because you didn't *key* the service:

```cs
// No key
builder
    .RegisterType<UpdateCustomerCommandHandler>()
    .As<ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>>();

// commandHandler key
builder
    .RegisterType<UpdateCustomerCommandHandler>()
    .Keyed<ICommandHandler<UpdateCustomerCommand>>("commandHandler");
```

But since you don't want to register all your handlers one by one, here's how to register them without *keying* them:

```cs
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

*/Edit*

I can see two scenarios where *keying* services can be useful:

- You have several types implementing the same interface and you want to inject different implementations in different services. Let's say, you register both `SqlConnection` and `DB2Connection` as `IDbConnection`. You then have 2 services, one which is supposed to target SQL Server, the other one DB2. If they both depend on `IDbConnection`, you want to make sure you inject the correct one in each service.
- If you use [decorators](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators), the way registrations work is you define the services to which the decorators will apply by a *key* - the first example is self-explanatory

Comment: In fact, I am using the Decorator pattern here, so I do need to have that key specified.  Why wouldn't Autofac look for the keyed version of this?  Apologies, but it doesn't seem like your answer has an answer in it.

Comment: Are you sure you use the Decorator pattern? The original question doesn't mention that you use it, and the .zip you linked to doesn't contain a decorator registration or a decorator implementation of `ICommandHandler`.  

Autofac by default tries to resolve *default* services, that is, the ones that are not explicitly *named* or *keyed*. If you want it to resolve such services, you have to be explicit about it.

Comment: When I created the sample project, it was a simplified version of my project.  You are correct that when I removed the line to register it as a keyed service, it was resolved successfully.  I just went ahead and added a decorator registration as well, and it is working as expected.  Must be something else different between my project and the sample provided.  Thanks, and I'll work to recreate and get back to you.

Comment: Alright sir, I've uncovered my mistake.  In an attempt to figure out how in heck my project was different from the sample I provided, I created a scrap copy of my project and tore it down to its simplest version.  Still was having the issue.  After much fiddling, I found what I had done.  In an effort to make the assembly scanning a little more elegant (which didn't work anyway), I renamed the output of the business logic assembly to something like mynamespace.BusinessLogic as opposed to just BusinessLogic.  So Autofac had been scanning the older version of this assembly.  Much cry, many thank

Comment: Glad to hear you worked out what was wrong. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if you feel it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Because Google brings you to this page even when you're trying to manually register types, I thought that even though this doesn't answer the asked question, it would be useful for future visitors. So, if you want to manually register a generic type, you would use this format:

```
service.AddTransient(typeof(IThing<>), typeof(GenericThing<>));
```

or if there's no interface, then just:

```
service.AddTransient(typeof(GenericThing<>));
```

and for completeness, if you have a generic with multiple types:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(GenericThing<,>));
```